# Access flutter secure storage values from native android app service

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, service, autofill

I am using [flutter secure storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) to write a value in Flutter. I believe flutter secure storage uses keystore for this. The code looks like this:

```
r = "whatever_string"
await storage.write(key: 'master', value: r);
```

I can retrieve the value in flutter like this:

```
await storage.read(key: 'master')
```

... but I am launching an android intent thread (in kotlin code) and that thread is called by the native android autofill service. I need that service intent to have access to the flutter secure storage value ('master') without launching the flutter app. Can I do this in the kotlin service, and if so, how?

Comment: You would probably need to write your own script. Perphaps looking at package's source code would help?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm currently doing. I was hoping someone had already done this ;)

Comment: seen the source code for that package though - seemed very poorly written. Forking and rewriting most of it was somewhere on the bottom of my todo list too.

Comment: Well if you reach that item on your to-do list, please let me know!

Comment: Looks like it uses shared prefs. Am I wrong? This is from the android FlutterSecureStoragePlugin.java file.    private void write(String key, String value) throws Exception {
        byte[] result = storageCipher.encrypt(value.getBytes(charset));
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(key, Base64.encodeToString(result, 0));
        editor.commit();
    }